# Kubernetes cannot cleanup Flannel

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

First I start Kubernetes using Flannel with `10.244.0.0`.

Then I reset all and restart with `10.84.0.0`.

However, the interface `flannel.1` still is `10.244.1.0`

That's how I clean up:

```
kubeadm reset
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
rm -rf /var/lib/cni/
rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*
rm -rf /run/flannel
rm -rf /etc/cni/
ifconfig cni0 down
brctl delbr cni0
ifconfig flannel.1 down
systemctl start docker
```

Am I missing something in the reset?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because your ip link have the old record

look by

`ip link`

you can see the record, and if you want to clean the record of old flannel and cni

please try

`ip link delete cni0
ip link delete flannel.1`

Comment: Please add a little more context around this answer.  Why does this fix the problem?  What did the original poster do wrong?  Your answer has been flagged for deletion, adding more could prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the original commands:

```
brctl delbr cni0
# deletes the cni0 interface
```

But the `ifconfig flannel.1 down` did not remove the interface. Thus:

```
ip link delete flannel.1
# deletes the flannel.1 interface
# also, 'ip link delete cni0' was unnecessary since the brctl command deleted the link
```